# Loop over cx_Oracle cursor stalls for several minutes

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I wrote a component which executes a series of dynamically-constructed queries against a database and eventually performs a final query whose results are fetched. All this logic is wrapped in a generator. Other components can hook-up to this generator and spool the results to a file, a tab-delimited text file in the case of this test. Here's the code of the generator function:

```
def cycle(self, schema, matchprofile, fixedcond):

    cursor = self.cursor
    cursor.set_schema(schema)
    cursor.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE schema.table')
    metaatts = self.get_metaattributes(schema)

    for condset in matchprofile:
        condsql = self.dostuffwith(self, matchprofile, fixedcond)
        qry = self.qrybase.replace('<<condset>>', condset).replace('<<condsql>>', condsql)
        cursor.execute(qry)             # queries performing logic aganst database

    cursor.execute(self.finalqry)           # select query extracting results

    for row in cursor:
        yield Row(row, metaatts.copy())

    if self.counts:
        self.counter.addto(cursor.rowcount)
```

The `cursor` is a subclassed 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' with an increased `arraysize` and an `outputtypehandler` that converts strings to Unicode.  `cycle` is called from another method which chains outputs for multiple input schemas into one stream.

```
cycles = itertools.imap(self.cycle, schemas, itertools.repeat(matchprofile), itertools.repeat(fixedcond))
rows = itertools.chain.from_iterable(cycles)
```

I run this on Python 2.6.

I ran the entire script dozens of times already and in most cases it took around 11 to 12 minutes to complete on the database schema. This is much more than expected. Unpredictably to me, in some attempts the script was done in about 55 seconds. That's just about what I expected based on the performance of a legacy script I'm trying to replace.

Since the new tool can take several database schemas as input parameters I also made test with supplying the same schema six times. The logged execution times were show that the issue occurred only in the first iteration:

```
:: 1597 records in 11:33
:: 1597 records in 0:56
:: 1597 records in 0:55
:: 1597 records in 0:55
:: 1597 records in 0:55
:: 1597 records in 0:55

:: total 9582 records in 16:10
```

I also managed to profile runs that produced a reasonable...

```
109707 function calls (109627 primitive calls) in 57.938 CPU seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    12   56.154    4.679   56.154    4.680 {function execute at 0x010074B0}
     1    0.819    0.819    0.819    0.819 ora.py:194(__init__)
     1    0.387    0.387    0.387    0.387 {function parse at 0x010075B0}
  1598    0.331    0.000   56.543    0.035 DuplicateDetector.py:219(cycle)
  1598    0.118    0.000    0.118    0.000 {method 'writerow' of '_csv.writer' objects}
 30295    0.029    0.000    0.029    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}
  1598    0.025    0.000   56.720    0.035 dsv.py:146(generate)
 30310    0.022    0.000    0.029    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'unicode' objects}
```

... and excessive timing.

```
109707 function calls (109627 primitive calls) in 701.093 CPU seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1598  644.514    0.403  699.827    0.438 DuplicateDetector.py:219(cycle)
    12   55.247    4.604   55.248    4.604 {function execute at 0x010084B0}
     1    0.783    0.783    0.783    0.783 ora.py:194(__init__)
     1    0.283    0.283    0.283    0.283 {function parse at 0x010085B0}
  1598    0.121    0.000    0.121    0.000 {method 'write' of '_csv.writer' objects}
 30295    0.036    0.000    0.036    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}
  1598    0.025    0.000  700.006    0.438 dsv.py:146(generate)
 30310    0.022    0.000    0.028    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'unicode' objects}
 30295    0.021    0.000    0.057    0.000 utf_8.py:15(decode)
```

It's clear that while in the first case database operations take most of the execution time, in the latter most of the time is spent in the `cycle` generator. I used the Idle debugger to execute this step by step and it seems that the line `for row in cursor:` is responsible for about 10 minutes of execution. I also noticed that memory usage of the python.exe process constantly increases during that time.

Now, the question is what happens in that line that the execution time of the same code is so different (although quite repeatable)? What kind of operations does cx_Oracle internally do when a Cursor is used as an iterator? What mistakes I could have made in the wrapping code that cause this? Admittedly, I've never seen anything similar happen with the old script which didn't use classes nor generators, but simply performed a  `fetchall` from the cursor.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this applies to your problem, but I've just stepped yesterday on a serious performance issue when setting a big arraysize to the cursor.

I had two methods using cursor.fetchall() and cursor.fetchmany().

The cursor.fetchall() was taking 0.1 sec to complete, cursor.fetchmany() 1,5 sec.

After some debugging I noticed that I was setting cursor.arraysize to a big value (100.000) before fetch_many(). This causes the cxOracle driver to allocate mem space for the arraysize num of rows. Combined with a query with lots of varchar2(4000) columns, this summed up to some x*100MB being allocated before each call and then freed.

Might be your problem, too.